# Does the dual inner product arise from a dual measure?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, dual-spaces

Follow up to this question: [Is there such a thing as a "dual measure"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833243/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-dual-measure?noredirect=1#comment7910128_3833243)

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $X : \Omega \to V$ a random vector in $L^2$ (this is maybe fuzzy)

The pushforward $\mu := X_* \mathbb{P}$ defines a measure on $V$.

This measure induces an inner product on $V^*$:

$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int f(v)g(v) \mathrm{d} \mu(v)$$

There's a natural dual inner product on $V$ that makes the Riesz representation into an isometry. (The distance coming from this inner product is used to define the Gaussian for instance)

Is there a kind of "dual measure" on $V^*$ that induces the dual inner product on $V$ as seen above?